# PHP querying MySQL returning Multiple Rows with only one Date

Tags: php

I always get confused when working with dates in PHP and MySQL.  I looked through other posts, but couldn't find a solution,

I have a simple blog stored in a database that echos records when queried.  I get multiple rows with multiple entries, but the date is the same on all of them.

The dates are stored with MySQL timestamp in a column called 'TimeStamp' and are formatted this way in the database:
2011-12-29 21:16:55 (for example).

Here's the query:

```
$set_select_sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM  `table` 
    ORDER BY  `table`.`TimeStamp` DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 30";
$set_query = mysql_query($set_select_sql);
$HowMany=mysql_num_rows($set_query);
$time = date("g:i a", strtotime(mysql_result($set_query,0,'TimeStamp')));
$date = date("F j, Y ", strtotime(mysql_result($set_query,0,'TimeStamp')));
$blogpost = mysql_result($set_query,0,'blogpost');

mysql_data_seek($set_query, 0);
$r = 0;
while ($r <= $HowMany) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set_query);
    if ($row == FALSE) {
    } else {
        extract($row);

        echo "It was $time on $date when I posted this.<br/>";
        echo "$blogpost"
    }
    $r++
```

Why am I only getting one date?
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You are setting your time and date variables to the values of the first row.  Then you loop through your records but you are not updating the time and date variables in your loop.

Comment: You can replace your `if($row == FALSE){}` with `if($row !== FALSE)` so you don't have to put your logic in an `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you output `$time` and `$date` there which were **NOT** fetched within the loop of your rows, but right before it.

The solution would be to fetch these variables within the loop as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set_query)) {
   $time = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['TimeStamp']));
   $date = date("F j, Y ", strtotime($row['TimeStamp']));
   $post = $row['blogpost'];

   echo "It was " . $time . " on " . $date . " that I posted this. <br />";
   echo $post;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the date of the first row found with this line:

```
$date = date("F j, Y ", strtotime(mysql_result($set_query,0,'TimeStamp')));
```

To get the date for every row, you need to get the date in the `while` loop and not before.